# Trying loop an mp3 and output the mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, mp3

I have a 7 second mp3. I want to loop it 3 times and give me back the output. It only plays once in the output, though.

I've tried setting the duration to 21 seconds instead (the atrim parameter), but in that case the output will only play once, and the remaining 14 seconds is silent.

```
ffmpeg -i explosion.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=end=7,aloop=loop=3:size=0[outa]" -map "[outa]" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop the whole input, you just use the stream_loop option:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 2 -i explosion.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp3
```

You can replace `-c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2` with `-c copy` but check if the loop joint is seamless.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the number of times you want it to loop is added onto the original sound, so I actually want 2 instead of 3 for `aloop`

For `size`, it needs to be in samples. So I multiply the duration of the sound in seconds times the sample rate, which is 44100. Final command is:

`ffmpeg -i explosion.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0,apad,atrim=end=7,aloop=loop=2:size=7*44100[outa]" -map "[outa]" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp3`